# Cypress component testing not recognizing new tests

Tags: reactjs, typescript, cypress

I duplicated the existing `App.test.tsx`, and cypress says it won't recognize any tests in my newly created `Button.test.tsx`.

This is my `Button.tsx` component:

```
import React from 'react';

const Button = ({text}: any) => {
  return <button>{text}</button>;
};

export default Button;
```

And this is my test:

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from '@cypress/react';
import Button from './Button';

it('renders button', () => {
  mount(<Button text="text"/>);
  cy.get('button').contains('text');
});
```

Cypress GUI says:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you've missed the [config step](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/component-testing/introduction#%EF%B8%8F-Existing-end-to-end-users) for component tests, e.g

```js
// cypress.json
{
  "testFiles": "cypress/integration/*.spec.js",
  "component": {
    "componentFolder": "src",
    "testFiles": ".*/__tests__/.*spec.tsx",
    "viewportHeight": 500,
    "viewportWidth": 700
  }
}
```

Or are you not running the component test runner?

```js
yarn cypress open-ct
```